# Neutrino Interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, neutrinos

Massive neutrinos are eigenstates of vacuum Hamiltonian. So any flavour can be expressed as a superposition of these states, and typical considerations of a 2-state system follow. What happens if neutrinos interact with matter and acquires an interaction energy? How to express the perturbation Hamiltonian and proceed?

Comment: This is called "MSW Effect" and has been worked out in textbook chapters with that name

Comment: @rfl Could you refer to any relevant resource?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikheyev%E2%80%93Smirnov%E2%80%93Wolfenstein_effect